# If statement in Wix installer bundle

Tags: wix, installation

I have a variable like this in bundle.wxs

```
<Variable Name="IsRegistryKeyExist"  />
```

Does a registry search to find whether a key exists.

```
<util:RegistrySearch
            Id="REGSEARCH"
            Root="HKLM"
            Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp\Test"
            Result="exists" 
            Variable="IsRegistryKeyExist"/>
```

Following if statement is present

```
<?if IsRegistryKeyExist = 0 ?>
<Variable Name="EneterdIfCase" Value="IfExecuted" />
<?else ?>
<Variable Name="EneterdIfCase" Value="ElseExecuted" />
<?endif ?>
```

When printing this varible in a custom action, it says "Else" part is getting executed regardless of the value of "IsRegistryKeyExist", basically it seems the if condition checking is not correct.

Following are the try-outs I have done so far.

```
<?if $(var.IsRegistryKeyExist) = 0 ?>
<?if <![CDATA[IsRegistryKeyExist = 0]]?>
<?if [IsRegistryKeyExist] = 0 ?>
<?if IsRegistryKeyExist = "0" ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with the "if else" behaviour? I assume you want to do two different things in both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <?if xxxxx ?> stuff is pre-processor stuff for compile time much like adding

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    Log(LogLeve.Debug, "Here's a message that only happens in debug builds when DEBUG is defined.");
#endif
```

to print debug messages only in debug builds of the product.

The reason you are getting always the else is because the pre-processor looks at the value of your "IsRegistryKeyExist" variable at compile time and you did not assign a value to it in your Variable declaration so it, *I think*, is set to empty/null/"". <?if "" = 0 ?> is always false so it only puts the else case into the file for the compiler to compile and completely omits the code in the "if" part. If you set Value="0" in your definition of the IsRegistryKeyExist variable it will always include the if portion of your preprocessor if-else.

[Here's a resource to the wix pre-processor.](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html)